# exit code from ssh command

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, exit-code

I'm trying to retrieve the code return from this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "CM  1"
ssh -i key/keyId.ppk user@X.X.X.X "
grep blabla ddd
if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then exit 1; fi
"
echo $?
```

But the last command `echo $?` returns 0 instead of 1.

And if try to run separately (not as a script) :

- the ssh command: `ssh -i key/keyId.ppk user@X.X.X.X`
- grep blabla ddd => I get the msg "grep: ddd: No such file or directory"
- then: if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then exit 1; fi
- then: echo $? => it returns 1 as expected

Do you have an idea why it doesn't work in my script ?

Thank you

Comment: what does it mean "returns nothing"? What version are you using? It works fine for me.

Comment: What is the reason behind the use of `ssh`'s `-t` ?

Comment: @Rany Albeg Wein : there was no special reason for the -t

Comment: @Jakuje : GNU bash, version 4.1.17(0)-release (i686-pc-cygwin)
I've edited my post, you are right it works in my1st version, but in this current version it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
ssh -i key/keyId.ppk user@X.X.X.X "
grep blabla ddd
if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then exit 1; fi
"
```

evaluates `$?` in your shell and not in the remote one, because the `$` is not escaped in single quotes. You should escape that to reach desired behaviour. Once to avoid evaluation in your local shell, for the second time to avoid evaluation when it is passed to the bash on remote side. Or rather put the command into single quotes:

```
ssh -i key/keyId.ppk user@X.X.X.X '
grep blabla ddd
if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then exit 1; fi
'
```

Comment: Also, comparing an exit status to 0 is what the `if` command does already! You don't need to use `[` and `$?`. `if ! grep blabla ddd` is equivalent.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley True. But I didn't want to spoil his algorithm :)